# how install jsonrpc on macos for python27

Tags: python, twisted

I want to check the operation of the code:

```
  from txjsonrpc.web import jsonrpc
  from twisted.web import server
  from twisted.internet import reactor

  class Math(jsonrpc.JSONRPC):
    """
    An example object to be published.
    """
  def jsonrpc_add(self, a, b):
    """
    Return sum of arguments.
    """
    return a + b

reactor.listenTCP(7080, server.Site(Math()))
reactor.run()
```

but I get an error message:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7/Users/___/server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/___/server.py", line 1, in <module>
    from txjsonrpc.web import jsonrpc
ImportError: No module named txjsonrpc.web

Process finished with exit code 1
```

run:
    pip install jsonprc
    Downloading/unpacking jsonprc
      Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement jsonprc
    Cleaning up...
    No distributions at all found for jsonprc

help the beginning programmer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation instructions are just one google search away:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txJSON-RPC/0.3

Happy hacking!